# How to close child window and redirect the link in parent current window

Tags: javascript

I'm getting some json data from the services and bind those values in the table format in the child window. Click on link in the child window, should close child window and redirect the url in parent current window.

```
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>sample</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var childWindow;
            function GenerateStudentsTable() {
                var jsondata = {
                    "school": {
                        "students": [{
                                "studentId": "Test1",
                                "Name": "Message01"
                            },
                            {
                                "studentId": "Test2",
                                "Name": "Message2"
                            }, {
                                "studentId": "Test3",
                                "Name": "Message3"
                            }
                        ],
                        "redirectURL" : "https://www.google.com/search"
                    }
                }

                var query = "students";
                var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
                table.border = "1";

                var headerLabels = ["Id", "Name"]
                var headerLabelsCount = headerLabels.length;

                var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                for (var i = 0; i < headerLabelsCount; i++) {
                    var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
                    headerCell.innerHTML = headerLabels[i];
                    row.appendChild(headerCell);
                }

                var jsonLength = Object.keys(jsondata.school.students).length;
                for (var i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++) {
                    row = table.insertRow(-1);
                    for (var j = 0; j < headerLabelsCount; j++) {
                        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                        if (j == 0) {
                            cell.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:window.opener.redirectToParentWindow()">' + jsondata.school.students[i].studentId + '</a>';
                        } else {
                            cell.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:window.opener.redirectToParentWindow()">' + jsondata.school.students[i].Name + '</a>';
                        }
                    }
                }

                childWindow = window.open("", "Title", "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=780,height=200,top=" + (screen.height - 400) + ",left=" + (screen.width - 840));
                childWindow.document.body.innerHTML = table.outerHTML;
            }

            function redirectToParentWindow()
            {
                childWindow.close();
                window.location.href =jsondata.school.redirectURL;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <input type="button" value="Generate Table" onclick="GenerateStudentsTable()" />
        <hr />
        <div id="dvTable">
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

I have no issues in the binding data in the child window but i'm not sure how to close the child window and redirect to link in parent window. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you can use a combination [`Window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between windows and [`Window.close`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) to close the required window. I'll try to spin up an answer once I'm on a laptop.

Comment: Poke around for "window.opener"

Comment: I modified the code and I'm able to close the child window but url is not loading.

Answer (score 0):

Below code changes are working as expected.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var childWindow, redirectUrl;
        function GenerateStudentsTable() {
            var jsondata = {
                "school": {
                    "students": [{
                        "studentId": "Test1",
                        "Name": "Message01"
                    },
                    {
                        "studentId": "Test2",
                        "Name": "Message2"
                    }, {
                        "studentId": "Test3",
                        "Name": "Message3"
                    }
                    ],
                    "redirectURL": "https://www.google.com/search"
                }
            }

            var query = "students";
            var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
            table.border = "1";

            var headerLabels = ["Id", "Name"]
            var headerLabelsCount = headerLabels.length;

            var row = table.insertRow(-1);
            for (var i = 0; i < headerLabelsCount; i++) {
                var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
                headerCell.innerHTML = headerLabels[i];
                row.appendChild(headerCell);
            }

            var jsonLength = Object.keys(jsondata.school.students).length;
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++) {
                row = table.insertRow(-1);
                for (var j = 0; j < headerLabelsCount; j++) {
                    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                    if (j == 0) {
                        cell.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:window.opener.redirectToParentWindow()">' + jsondata.school.students[i].studentId + '</a>';
                    } else {
                        cell.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:window.opener.redirectToParentWindow()">' + jsondata.school.students[i].Name + '</a>';
                    }
                }
            }
            redirectUrl = jsondata.school.redirectURL.concat("?q=query");
            childWindow = window.open("", "Title", "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=780,height=200,top=" + (screen.height - 400) + ",left=" + (screen.width - 840));
            childWindow.document.body.innerHTML = table.outerHTML;

        }

        function redirectToParentWindow() {
            childWindow.close();
            window.location.href = redirectUrl;
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="Generate Table" onclick="GenerateStudentsTable()" />
    <hr />
    <div id="dvTable">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```